# Updating graphic drivers because Maple is unable to render 3D graphics with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm trying to plot a 3D graph with Maple on Ubuntu 14.04, but I get the following error:

> Maple is unable to render 3D graphics
>   Your operating system, graphics, or video driver may require updating
>   see "gldriver" in the help system for more information
>   GLException
>   Unable to create OpenGL context

The [Maple website](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/faqs/detail.aspx?sid=33530) recommends the following solution:

> Maple is attempting to use hardware rendering but is unable to properly access the graphics hardware. A graphics driver update will likely resolve this.

But I'm not sure how to best proceed with updating the graphic driver since my system is up to date. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Here is the output of `inxi -AG`

```
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller   
       X.Org: 1.17.1 drivers: nvidia,intel Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz   
       GLX Renderer: GeForce 820M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.96
```

Here is the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

and `lspci | grep 3D`

```
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: hmm give output of lspci | grep VGA and lspci | grep 3D.

Comment: @philsegeler I've edited my message with the information you've requested.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Uninstall the currently installed drivers 340.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Step 2 : Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers 352.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case it does not work install the latest official drivers 358.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case it still does not work use another installation method.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ... enter  user name and password ...
Now execute the commands ...

Comment: Hi cl-netbox, thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, neither of them work, Maple still gives the same error. I have +1 your answer, because I have now installed the latest official NVIDIA drivers 358, which (I assume) is better than what I had before.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, before doing anything.. try "glxinfo | grep OpenGL" and "glxgears"
and post output, if they show an error, then your drivers are broken.

According to the output of lspci | grep VGA and 3D you have 1 intel and 1 nvidia card which means OPTIMUS.

i suggest you uninstall purge everything related to the nvidia-drivers, and install bumblebee.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-prime nvidia-358

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-358 nvidia-settings primus
```

then you need to sudo gedit /etc/modules and add

```
i915

bbswitch
```

in order to load the intel driver and the bbswitch module( which controls if your card is on or off)

then you need to sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf and make sure the line

```
blacklist nvidia-358
```

is there, if not add it.

That prevents nvidia-358 to be loaded on boot interfering with the intel one.

finally you need to sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

line 22: >Driver=nvidia

line 55: >KernelDriver=nvidia-358

line 58: >LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-358:/usr/lib32/nvidia-358

line 61: >XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-358/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

to make the nvidia opengl libraries visible to "optirun"/"primusrun".

reboot.

put in terminal:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

and:

```
primusrun glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

Explanation: "primusrun" (or "optirun") executes the given program in the nvidia card.

If both run successfully (they should), then your OpenGL drivers should work correctly and you should be able to run maple, else please post any error outputs of those terminal commands.

if one of them (for some strange reason) doesnt work, try running maple with the working one to see if it works!

See more here: http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.gr/2015/05/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-driver-in.html

Samsung NP550P5C-S02GR Intel Core i5-3210M HD 4000, Nvidia Geforce GT 650M Ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: Hi thanks, for the your elaborate reply (+1), I've followed all your steps successfully and I don't get any error from the terminal commands. Unfortunately, maple still doesn't plot the 3d graph. I think I'll sent an email to Maple and see what they say. Again thanks for your help.