# Confusion about what password one should use for the `sudo` command

Tags: login, password

Yester I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717720/updating-graphic-drivers-because-maple-is-unable-to-render-3d-graphics-with-ubun/717762#717762) question, and tried to follow cl-netbox's advice:

> Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the `E` key.
>   Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press `F10` to boot.
>   On login screen press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` ... enter user name and password ...
>   Now execute the commands ...

After pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` at the login screen and writing `sudo apt-get update`, the laptop asks me for my password (as per usual). However, the password that I normally always use does not work. I've no idea what password I should use. Anybody can help me?

Comment: *"does not work"* - what happens exactly? what is the error message?

Comment: That my password is not correct. @steeldriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a nonprivileged user runs `sudo <command>`, he/she is asked for his/her password, not the root password.  (It makes sense -- if the user knows the root password, he/she wouldn't need to use sudo.)

So, since all the user need is his/her password, does that mean that any user is allowed to run any command as root? Certainly not; which user can run which command as root, and other limitations, is all specified in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a bit confused by your answer, but I willing to learn. Do you know of any document where I can read more about this? Please note that I'm the only user on this laptop (which is my own laptop).

Comment: Here's a tutorial about sudo: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo . There are many other docs, I'd recommend that you google for "linux sudo tutorial" and read around a bit. Also, remember that you have manual pages on Linux which are the best reference you can get: just type "man sudo" as a shell command.